# how to give link to the label and pass querystring to another page in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have asp.net page with SQL server 2008 as database. I have 3 stored procedures . one for total  count of users in tbl_users and onother for total man users and last for woman users. and i have 3 labels for display count of records. I Want to give link to the labels so that when we click on label, open another page and run related stored procedure. and show detail in grid view.
For e.g :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClXVO.png)

```
<a href="show_records.aspx?val="+Label1.Text;"><asp:Label ID="lbl_total_records" runat="server"
</asp:Label></a>
```

But this code dont work . please help me.

Comment: Please read this, then re-write your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you are trying to do is this:

```
<a href="show_records.aspx?val=<%=lbl_total_records.Text%>"><asp:LabelID="lbl_total_records" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label></a>
```

This will properly concatenate the text of the label to your link. The "<%= %>" tags are shortcut for Response.Write().

You can then get the value from your query string on the show_records.aspx page like this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["val"] != null)
{
     string value = Request.QueryString["val"].ToString();
     //logic here to call the correct stored procedure based on value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LinkButton` control instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnk_total_records" />
```

This functions the same as an HTML anchor tag but allows you to set the attributes from the code behind like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lnk_total_records.Text = "LinkText";
    lnk_total_records.PostBackUrl = "show_records.aspx?val=LinkText";
}
```